# Refactoring from anonymous type to defined type

Tags: c#, lambda

I've been tasked with refactoring some code so that it is changed from an anonymous type to a well defined type. However, this anonymous type is defined inside a lambda expression and I'm not too sure how to go about setting it (I'm very new to using lambda).

Here's the logic with the anonymous type:

```
var groupedData = exportData.GroupBy(x => x.Key.MetricInstance.EntityID)
                            .Select(grp => new
                                           {
                                               k = grp.Key,
                                               v = grp.Select(x => new
                                                                   {
                                                                       trm = x.Key,
                                                                       tsd = x.Value
                                                                   })
                                                      .ToList()})
                            .ToList();
```

The target in question is the k and v variables respectively. k is an int and v is a dictionary. I have created a new class to hold this data:

```
public class EntityMetricData
{
    public int entityID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<TRInfo, List<TimeData>> entityMetrics { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to store the value of k inside the entityID field and the value of v inside the dictionary, how can I go about doing this? I've tried something like this but it doesn't compile:

```
var grouping = csvData.GroupBy(x => x.Key.MetricInstance.EntityID)
                      .Select(grp => new EntityMetricData emd
                                     {
                                       emd.entityID = grp.Key, 
                                       emd.entityMetrics = grp.Select(x => new
                                                                           {
                                                                             trm = x.Key,
                                                                             tsd = x.Value
                                                                           })
                                                              .ToList() })
                      .ToList();
```

I get an error saying that "grp doesn't exist in the current context".

Comment: Remove `emd` everywhere

Comment: What is `TRInfo` and `TimeData`? Your original data just had a list of key/values for `entityMetrics` but the refactored one changes it to a `Dictionary<TRInfo,List<TimeData>>` - there is no obvious conversaion there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `emd` variable:

```
var grouping = csvData
  .GroupBy(x => x.Key.MetricInstance.EntityID)
  .Select(grp => new EntityMetricData { 
     entityID = grp.Key, 
     entityMetrics = grp
       .Select(x => new { 
          trm = x.Key, 
          tsd = x.Value })
       .ToList() })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: It's not that you don't need it: it's invalid code.